# Orthogonal decomposition of vector v with respect to span W

Tags: matrices, vectors, orthogonality, matrix-decomposition

I need to find the orthogonal decomposition of vector V
with respect to span W

$$
v=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 \\ -1 \\ 5 \\ 6 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
w = span
        \begin{pmatrix}
                \begin{bmatrix}
                1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 
                \end{bmatrix},
                \begin{bmatrix}
                1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 1
                \end{bmatrix}
        \end{pmatrix} 
$$

I know that $ v = y + z $ where $ y \in W $ and $ z \in \text{orthogonal complement of W} $

Answer (score 1):

Project $v$ onto $W$:

$$\begin{align}
\text{proj}_W v &= \frac{1}{3} \cdot \left( \begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 & 5 & 6 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \right ) \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + \frac{1}{3}\left( \begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 & 5 & 6 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \right ) \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 2 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

Then, $z$ is given by $z = v - \text{proj}_Wv$:
$$\begin{align}
z &= v - \text{proj}_Wv \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -1 \\ 5 \\ 6 \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ -3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

$z$ is indeed orthogonal to $W$ since its dot product with both vectors in the spanning set for $W$ is 0.

Comment: Isn't z's dot product with the second vector in the span not 0?
Thanks for the help though

Comment: @MaxFiltenborg $(-1)(1) + (-3)(0) + (4)(-1) + (5)(1) = -1 + 0 -4 + 5 = 0$